# Coat Of Arms And Goblin Tokens

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I currently have a Goblin deck, it constantly racks up 1/1 goblin creatures. I now place [Coat Of Arms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191314) onto the battlefield. I have 100 1/1 goblin tokens on the battlefield, a goblin warrior and a goblin shaman does this mean each goblin creature gets +3/+3? Do goblin tokens count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of your creatures (including the token goblins) get +101/+101. I hope your opponent has a sweeper.

I think your confusion comes from misreading the things that are being counted. You don't count the number of different types: *each* creature counts the number of *other creatures* that share at least one subtype. (In the card's example, the **two** *Goblin Warriors* and *Goblin Shaman* share the subtype *Goblin*.)

And yes, the tokens count. They may not be cards (technically they don't count as cards even if you use token-cards), but they are permanents, creatures, and goblins.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 100 goblin tokens, a goblin warrior, a goblin shaman, and no other player has goblins, warriors and shamans, all your creatures will have +101/+101.

[Coat of Arms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426630) affects all creatures on the battlefields, counting the number of creatures that share a type, so in your case warrior and shaman don't matter, because each goblin will see 101 other goblins and get +1/+1 for each other goblin. If another player were playing goblins, they would get the same bonus, and it would be bigger. If another player were playing warriors, your goblin warrior would get a bonus from the other player's warriors, but they would get a bonus from your goblin warrior (not the 100s, since those came from being goblins.) A creature with changeling would get a bonus from all creatures on the board, since the changeling has all types.

[Door of Destinies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433140) is a similar card that cares about casted creatures of a chosen type, not creatures in play. For [Door of Destinies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433140), the cast does not need to be successful, just have the right type to add power, and tokens would not add to the size, but would get the bonus, since they are never cast.